# Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, android-support-library

Знающие люди, гуру, гении, кто угодно помогите, не могу понять почему падает приложение.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.kechinde.likeber, PID: 23673
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kechinde.likeber/com.kechinde.likeber.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(Native Method)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at com.kechinde.likeber.MainActivityFragment.onCreateView(MainActivityFragment.java:30)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1065)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1268)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1370)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2415)
at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:169)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(Native Method)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(Native Method)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at com.kechinde.likeber.MainActivityFragment.onCreateView(MainActivityFragment.java:30)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1065)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1268)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1370)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2415)
at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:4
```

Мне не нравится конец лога - видно, что он обрезанный видимо не хватило места в logcat. Как я знаю большие сообщения в него целиком не отправишь.
Вот fragment_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main_fragment" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Попробуйте убрать из тулбара всё, кроме размеров и ID

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, к сожалению не помогло - ничего не изменилось, падает с такой же ошибкой.

Comment: Попробуйте высщту в wrap_content поставить. Если не поможет - попробуйте потереть папку с СДК и загрузить всё заново

Comment: Тоже не редко сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой. Однако мне всегда помогает Clear- Rebuild.

Comment: @m-g-demin, сразу пробовал - не помогло.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ни первое, ни второе не помогло